# Passing a record type via a link

Tags: url

I am using ClonePlus, and I want to pass a record type along with my button link.

```
    /apex/ClonePlus?id=
{! Product2.Id }&{!Product2.RecordType}='Configuration'&childobjecttypes=Product_Configuration__c
```

It would be great if someone could help.
Thanks, Lily

Comment: try passing in the record type Id instead of the name in the url parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that too, and it doesn't work either. I suspect that something is wrong in the format of that url?

Comment: Can you try replacing "=" after {!Product2.RecordType} with something other that you can use as identifier to break the string later on? Like "$" or something ? The reason being, URL parameters are in key->value pair and each pair separeted by "&", but that "=" sign might be disturbing the key value pair